# How does one apply the Bessel and the Parseval equality to a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given the system: $$\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int} \}_{n\in \mathbb{Z} } \ \text{in} \ C[0,2\pi]$$

How does one apply the Bessel and the Parseval equality to the functions $f(t) = t $ and $g(t)=t^2$ ?

Attempt so far:

for : $s_{f,m} := \frac{1}{2} a_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{m} (a_{n}cos(nt)+b_{n}sin(nt))$ the Bessel equality is : $$||f - S_{f,m} ||^2 = ||f||^2 - [\frac{1}{2}a_{0}^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{m} (a_{k}^2 + b_{k}^2)]$$ and the Parseval equality is given by: $$\frac{1}{2} a_{0}^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_{k}^2 + b_{k}^2) = || f||^2 $$

where  $||f|| = (f,f)^{1/2} = (\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^2)^{1/2}$

$$||t||^2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}t^2dt = \frac{8}{3}\pi^3, ||t^2||^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}t^4 dt = \frac{32}{5}\pi^5$$

I don't see how to continue from here if this is correct at all

Comment: Why are you using a sine and cosine representation of the Fourier series when you speak of a complex exponential basis?

Comment: I found a lot of versions for both equalities, I picked this one because I thought it doesn't matter since : $e^{int} = cos(nt)+isin(nt)$? Which one would be better in your opinion?

Comment: Well, at a very high level, it doesn't.  But it does point to why you are having trouble.  You need to pick a basis and a representation consistent with that basis.  Anyway, Parseval will produce an interesting sum, in these cases something akin to a Riemann zeta.

Answer (score 2):

For $f(t)=t$, the $c_n$ which form the representation of the basis $\{e^{i n t} {C[-\pi,\pi]}\}$ are

$$c_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \; \forall n \ne 0$$
$$c_0=0\; n =0$$

Parseval tells us that

$$2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dt \: t^2 $$

The result gives $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$.

Comment: How did you find $c_n $, by what formula(e) ? Why did you change the interval from $[0,2\pi]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$? and where does that $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ in your last line when equating the sum come from?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I changed to $[-\pi,\pi]$ because I like symmetric intervals better.  I used $c_n = (1/(2 \pi)) \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} dt \: f(t) e^{i n t}$

Comment: in your last line you get : $$\sum \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{2\pi ^3}{3}$$ , I can't say , what went wrong?

Comment: My apologies, I left out the factor of 2 on the LHS.  That comes from the fact that the sum is actually from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and I used symmetry.